# Sorting in Dojo 1.5 datagrid doesn't work

Tags: sorting, datagrid, dojo

I have built a dojo 1.5 datagrid + dojox.data.JsonRestStore.  When the grid renders I can see the "carrot" that shows that sorting has fired and is on defaulting the right column. However, the content of the column(string values - field: 'projectShortName',...see code below) are not actually sorted. Hitting the descending/ascending button doesn't change the order or the rows. They are essentially locked in. I am not sure why?

I have column sorting turned off for certain columns and on for others using the canSort(). I only have formatters for calls with columns that have the sort turned OFF. I have tried making all columns sortable or only just the one that I really wanted. No dice.

Here is the layout/grid code:
var layout = [{
        field: '_item',
        name:  '&nbsp',
        formatter: selectFormatter,
        width: '25px'
    },
    {
        field: 'projectName',
        name: 'Project Name',
        width: '325px'
    },
    {
        field: 'projectShortName',
        name: 'Short Name',
        width: '80px'
    },
    {
        field: 'projectAreaName',
        name: 'RQM Project Area',
        width: '175px'
    },
    {
        field: '_item',
        name: 'Test Guide Status',
        width: '190px',
        formatter: testCaseGenerationOptionFormatter
    },
    {
        field: 'projectOwner',
        name: 'Owner',
        width: '140px'
    },
    {
        field: 'projectCreationTime',
        name: 'Created Date',
        width: '100px'
    },
    {
        field: 'projectLastUpdateTime',
        name: 'Last Modified Date',
        width: '120px'
    }];

```
dojo.empty(dojo.byId('workspaceGridContainer'));
if (dijit.byId("projectGrid")) {
    dijit.byId("projectGrid").destroyRecursive();
}

// Create a new grid:
var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
    id:'projectGrid',
    onHide: dojo.hitch(this, function() {
          dijit.byId("projectGrid").destroyRecursive();
      }),
    store: jsonStore,
    clientSort: true,
    autoHeight: true,
    //sortInfo: "-2",
    selectionMode: 'single',
    rowsPerPage: '100',
    structure: layout
},document.createElement('div'));

dojo.byId("workspaceGridContainer").appendChild(grid.domNode);

// Call startup, in order to render the grid:
grid.startup();

//var test = grid.setSortInfo(obj);
// Prevent sorting on column 1
grid.canSort = function(col){ if((Math.abs(col) == 1) || (Math.abs(col) == 5) || (Math.abs(col) == 6) || (Math.abs(col) == 7) || (Math.abs(col) == 8)) { return false; } else { return true; } };

var index = grid.getSortIndex();
if(index!=2) {
    if(grid.canSort(2)){
        grid.setSortIndex(2, false);
    }
}
```

---

As you can see commented out I have tried sortInfo as well. Any advice would be appreciated!
-Doug

Answer (score 0):

You may be using the wrong comparison operator.  The dojo documentation uses the strict equal '===' whereas you only use the equal '=='.  This causes problems in js, especially when you're comparing a literal, i.e. '1' with an object: 'Math.abs(col).  The official grid.canSort method should be coded as follows:

```
function canSort(col){ return Math.abs(col) === 2;}
```

Note Mozilla's description of the equal operator, and the type conversion js uses to resolve different data types: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Equal (==) - If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript converts the operands then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a number or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if possible; else if either operand is a string, the other operand is converted to a string if possible. If both operands are objects, then JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in memory.

Comment: Hi TedPrz, I tried the above (using ===) and it didn't work. I don't think the issue is strictly whether the column can sort or not. I already am able to see the sort "carrot" in the table head on the correct rows and no carrot on the rows that I don't want to sort on. So I assume that that code is not the issue? The issue is that whether the sort is descending or ascending the order never changes and it is clearly not alphabetical.  Of course I am assuming that the sort should be alphabetical. :)
-Doug